# How to export site themes from sharepoint 2010 to sharepoint 2013 manually?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I'm downloading a theme from Sharepoint 2010 and uploading it in site themes in Sharepoint 2013. But, I'm unable to see it in "Look and Feel".

How to do it ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming. This question might be on-topic for http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answer . I found something that says we can't export themes from SP2010 to SP2013 because SharePoint 2013 does not support “THMX” Themes that are Created in SharePoint 2010. If you are looking to migrate a Custom Theme from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013, you would have to re-design the Theme with new structure, defined by XML files – SPColor.xml and SPFont.xml and then apply to the new SharePoint 2013 site.

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/06/03/create-custom-theme-in-sharepoint-2013-step-by-step-tutorial/

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Branding-issues-that-may-occur-when-upgrading-to-SharePoint-2013-0c849002-cdf4-4843-9d4a-0a643a7c64f3

Answer (score 0):

Have tried themes creation steps for Sharepoint 2013 :

**To add a composed look**

1. Choose the Settings icon, and then choose Site settings.
2. Under Web Designer Galleries, choose Composed looks.
3. In the Composed Looks list, select new item.
4. In the Title text box, enter a title for the design
5. In the Name text box, enter a name for the design. The name appears
   in the Composed Looks list and in the design gallery.
6. In the Master Page URL text box, enter the URL of the master page.
   The URL can be a relative URL.
7. In the Theme URL text box, enter the URL of the color palette (the
   URL to the . spcolor file). The URL can be a relative URL.
8. In the Image URL text box, enter the URL of the background image.
   This is optional. The URL can be a relative URL.
9. In the Font Scheme URL text box, enter the URL of the font scheme
   (the URL to the .spfont file). This is optional. The URL can be a
   relative URL.
10. In the Display Order text box, enter the display order number. This
     determines where the design appears in the design gallery.
11. Choose Save.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj927175.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

http://en.share-gate.com/blog/create-sharepoint2013-theme-using-color-palette-tool

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but I am exporting the theme from 2010 environment and the process you are telling is for creating a new one. I am actually uploading a theme which is downloaded from 2010 environment and there is no master page options So it is not working.

Comment: Try creating sample master page in SP 2013 designer manager, then give reference to 2010 CSS file in newly created master page , upload master page along with 2010 themes files . I'm not fully sure but you can give a try

Comment: Hi it will not work. I have found some reasons that says we cant do it . I am posting the answer ,you can check it.